# is it possible to do item aggregtions only on the aggregations that are returned in the current query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to enrich my documents with some aggregations about them.

```json
"item": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "_id",
                "size": 50
            },
            "aggs": {
                "avgSize": {
                    "avg": {
                        "field": "contracts.dollarsObligated"
                    }
                },
                "awardingAgency": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "contracts.awardingAgency.keyword"
                    }
                },
            }
        }
```

I'm going to return 50 results per page, is there any way to ensure that those aggregations are run on the 50 aggregations that are returned in this query? Or should I do a second query for that ?

Comment: The aggregation will be applied to the entire index.
In your first pagination, you will already have the aggregation, in the next pagination, you would not need to aggregate again.

Comment: I'm returning documents. I want the item aggregations applied only to the documents in each page. Is that possible or must it be a new query, specified with the ids of the search result

Comment: The way you want, there's no way. You would have to pass the ids as you said.